# Difference between two derivative operator given in Jackson's book

Tags: special-relativity, mathematical-physics

As I was reading Jackson (3rd edition), On page 543 I see two different types of derivatives. they are given,

(11.76)
$$ {\partial^\alpha} {\equiv} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha} = (\frac{\partial}{\partial {x^0}}, -\nabla) $$

$$ {\partial_\alpha} {\equiv} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha} = (\frac{\partial}{\partial {x^0}}, \nabla) $$
and another equation,

(11.77)
$$ {\partial^\alpha}{A_\alpha} = {\partial_\alpha}{A^\alpha} = \frac{\partial A^0}{\partial x^0} + \nabla.\vec{A}$$

Now I have two doubts.

1) Let consider any derivative ${\partial^\alpha}$, then we are taking derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}$, Now here if our derivative is "contravariant" then why we are taking derivative with respect to "covariant" $x_\alpha$ , similar for another derivative.

2)Is it compulsory to take "contravariant" derivative ${\partial^\alpha}$ with covariant component $A_\alpha$ and vice versa, Why we would that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates are $x^\alpha$. There is no coordinate $x_\alpha$ as coordinates are not vectors and cannot have their indices raised a lowered by the metric. Instead
$$
\partial_\alpha \equiv  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}, \quad \partial^\alpha\equiv  g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta.
$$
If you want an invariant you must contract an upper index with a lower index. Either $\partial_\mu A^\mu$ or 
$
\partial^\mu A_\mu
$ will do, as they are equal.

Comment: So in Jackson is this misprinting? why they have written $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}$ ?

Comment: Ugh! I looked up Jackson and saw what you saw.  This is appalling. He should know better than to be so misleading. So, no it is not a misprint. It's just WRONG.

Comment: Well, in flat spacetime, you can treat inertial frame coordinates as vectors, right? Because displacement from the origin is a vector in flat spacetime. I would agree that is bad practice to do so as it doesn't smoothly generalize to general relativity but Jackson is limiting his focus to flat spacetimes I suppose.

Comment: By "Wrong" i mean that if you try to use such a language in General relatvity you will get totally wrong answers. He can define what he likes in the limited range of his book, but it is unadvisable to  use it.  Even in flat space coordintes are not vectors as they choose a fixed origin. $dx^\mu$ is Ok as a vector but not $x^\mu$ on its own.

Comment: Ok now, my question is are all  coordinates $x^\alpha$ are contravariant in nature?

Comment: @anbhadane That should probably be a different question (if one doesn't already exist) but essentially, no, coordinates are neither covariant nor contravariant in general, you cannot seek meaning out of the placement of the indices for coordinates because coordinates don't transform as tensorial objects.

Comment: No.  Contravariant *vectors* are elements of the tangent space at a point and covariant *vectors* are elements of the associated dual space. The metric allows a 1-1 mapping from the vector space to its dual.  I stress again that coordinates, even Cartesian coordinates,  are not vectors. It makes no sense to add them. How would you interpret the sum of two  spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: @mikestone sorry but I do not know about tangent space and associated dual basis, can you explain it to me?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Oh, I was confused with just by looking at indices, thank you.

Comment: @mikestone thank you, I got it about tangent space and dual basis. And again thank you for your answer.